# Javascript Check if three values are equal within tolerance of 2

Tags: javascript, comparison

I want to check if 3 RGB values are basically equal but sometimes the values are 1 or even 2 out either way so it's not so straightforward. So `90,90,90` should be equal as should `90,88,90`.

At the minute the best I came up with was something like:

```
if (r != g && r != b) {
  if ((r != b && r != (b - 1))) {
    // etc
  }
}


Expected output:
91,90,90 = true
93,89,93 = false
91,90,89 = true
```

Comment: You mean that there can be difference of `1` or `2` b/w values?

Comment: @Maheer Ali Yes so the expected output would be produced.

Comment: Please see the edit and the comments. I have fixed some of the issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `every()` on the array and check if the absolute difference b/w the each value with minimum(or maximum) is less than `2` or equal to `2`

```js
const checkRBG = arr => {
  let min = Math.min(...arr);
  return arr.every(x => Math.abs(min-x) <=2);
}

const tests = [
  [91,90,90],
  [93,89,93],
  [91,90,89],
  [90,88,92]
]

tests.forEach(x => console.log(checkRBG(x)))
```

Comment: what's with [90,88,92]? For me it looks like you don't compare arr[1] with arr{2], where diff is 4

Comment: @Turo Nice catch mate. I have updated the answer please check it. There is no need to compare with all the elements just need to get max or min and then use that in place of `arr[0]`